Generate stable combinations of an unsorted list in python
I have a list made of strings which are not in sorted order. I wish to generate combinations but in such a way that the order of the elements is as in the list. However, Python documentation and its behavior confuses me. To quote:

The combination tuples are emitted in lexicographic order according to the order of the input iterable. If the input iterable is sorted, the output tuples will be produced in sorted order.

Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. If the input elements are unique, there will be no repeated values within each combination.


I experimented a little and found the following behavior in Python 3.12.4:
>>> [c for c in combinations([7,3,4],2)]
[(7, 3), (7, 4), (3, 4)]

>>> [c for c in combinations({7,3,4},2)]
[(3, 4), (3, 7), (4, 7)]

While the first outcome that uses a list solves by purpose, it seems to contradict the documentation and may not be reliable. The second outcome that uses sets, however, is consistent with the documentation but does not serve my purpose.
I would be grateful for any clarification on these observations.
PS: I understand that the problem can be solved using additional list comprehension, but I would like to avoid it if that step is not required.

Why do you think the first one contradicts the documentation? They are in the order of the input iterable and is what you want.

Because the 1st says 'lexicographic order' and not the 'input order'.

“ Lexicographic order according to the order of the input iterable”. The input order defines the lexicographic sequence

In your second test you used a set rather than list. Sets don't have any order, so you get unpredictable results.

@MarkTolonen, how is the order of input different from the lexicographic order? If so IMHO, Pt.1 is redundant due to Pt.2.

If it helps, you can imagine it as enumerate([7, 3, 4]) in lexicographic order according to <.

A lexicographic order is a defined order, not necessarily numerical order.  The input iterable [7, 3, 4] defines the order.  Think of it as 7 < 3 < 4.  As Barmar stated, A set has no defined order, but iterating it (on my system, yours may vary) for n in {7,3,4}: print(n)  outputs 3 4 7, so 3 < 4 < 7 for the set and gives the 2nd result.  Your first experiment will give you exactly what you want.

Pt. 2 is indicating that if you have duplicate elements, e.g. [7, 3, 7] indicates 7 (first) < 3 < 7 (last), so you'll get (7, 3), (7, 7), (3, 7) for combinations([7, 3, 7],  2).  You'll always get positions (1st, 2nd), (1st, 3rd), (2nd, 3rd) for a 3-element iterable taken 2 at a time. the positions matter.
